# Integrals and equality

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are two nonnegative random variables on a probability space $(E, \mathcal{A}, P) $ such that $\forall B \in \mathcal{A}, \int_B X dP =\int_B Y dP. $
Let $k \in \mathbb{N} $. 
I want to prove that
$$\forall B \in \mathcal{A}, \int_B \min(X, k) dP =\int_B \min( Y, k) dP. $$
 I tried to to write $B=B \cap (X \leq k, Y \leq k) \cap (X \leq k, Y > k) \cap  (X >k, Y \leq k) \cap (X >k, Y > k)$ and then to integrate by it didn't work.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Define the set 
$$
B_n:=\{X\geqslant Y+1/n\}\cap \{X\leq n\}\cap \{Y\leq n\}.
$$
Then $$\mathbb E\left[X\mathbf 1_{B_n}\right]\geqslant\mathbb E\left[\left(Y+\frac 1n\right)\mathbf 1_{B_n}\right]=\mathbb E\left[Y\mathbf 1_{B_n}\right]+\frac 1n\mathbb P\left(B_n\right).$$
Use the assumption to conclude that $B_n$ has probability $0$. The union of $B_n$ has also probability $0$ and $\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}B_n=\{X>Y\}$ has probability zero. Similarly $\{Y>X\}$ has also probability zero.